# Attachment_fu: can't disable :partition option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, attachment-fu

I'm trying to use the [Attachment_Fu plugin](http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu) in a Rails project, and want to customize the paths where uploaded files are saved.

The documentation shows this option:

> :partition        # Whether to
>   partiton files in directories like
>   /0000/0001/image.jpg. Default is true.

(The 0001 part is an ID from a table.) I don't want that, so I set the partition option to false, like so:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attachment :content_type => :image,
                 :storage => :file_system,
                 :max_size => 500.kilobytes,
                 :resize_to => '320x200',
                 :thumbnails => {:thumb => '100x100>' },
                 :partition => false
  validates_as_attachment
end
```

...but the `:partition => false` option has no effect.

**Has anybody else encountered this problem? How did you fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may also need to specify

```
:path_prefix => 'your/path'
```

If you are disabling the auto partitioning.

Comment: This doesn't solve it. The paths are like `/photos/0000/0002/image.jpg` with just `:partition => false`. If I add `:path_prefix => public/images/#{table_name}`, I get paths like `/images/photos/0000/0002/image.jpg`. I want to get rid of the "0000/0002" part.